# 指定要素内にある指定文字列で始まる<input type text>内の特定属性名を全て、JavaScript か jQueryを使用して配列へ格納したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

**やりたいこと1**
・target id 内にある input type="text" で、nameがhoge_ で始まるものを全て、nameAry配列へ格納したい
・期待しているnameAry配列結果 ['hoge_1', 'hoge_2', 'hoge_3'];

**やりたいこと2**
・target id 内にある input type="text" で、idがpiyo_ で始まるものを全て、idAry配列へ格納したい
・期待しているidAry配列結果 ['piyo_1', 'piyo_2', 'piyo_3'];

---

**対象のHTML (例)**

```html
<form id="target">
  //中略
  <input type="text" name="hoge_1" id="piyo_1">
  //中略
  <input type="text" name="hoge_2" id="piyo_2">
  //中略
  <input type="text" name="hoge_3" id="piyo_3">
  //中略
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[属性セレクタ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)で絞り込んでから、それらの要素の `name`, `id` 属性を [`map` メソッド](https://api.jquery.com/map/)で得ることで、そのような動作が実現出来ます。

```js
const attrs = (attr, value) => $(`input[type="text"][${attr}^="${value}"]`)
  .map((i, e) => $(e).attr(`${attr}`))
  .toArray();

const nameAry = attrs("name", "hoge_");
const idAry = attrs("id", "piyo_");

console.log(nameAry); //=> Array(3) [ "hoge_1", "hoge_2", "hoge_3" ]
console.log(idAry); //=> Array(3) [ "piyo_1", "piyo_2", "piyo_3" ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target">
  <input type="text" name="hoge_1" id="piyo_1">
  <input type="text" name="hoge_2" id="piyo_2">
  <input type="text" name="hoge_3" id="piyo_3">
</form>
```